# Смена пользователя в mysql без quit

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер!
Подскажите как с пользователя root в командной строке перейти к другому пользователю без quit

Comment: Эмм.. команды “sudo” в mysql нет.

Comment: Никак невозможно. Такая архитектура by design.